# RedeclareSectionCommand/beforeskip not working with KOMA

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

I am trying to modify the spacing before and after the section title (should also work for the TOC) with \RedeclareSectionCommand. Modifying the value of "afterskip" does change the distance between the section title and the text. However, changing the value of "beforeskip" does nothing. I dont want to use \vspace*{} for that. There are a lot of posts about that but everything I tried did not work.

In the past I used the titlesec package and following command to modify the spacing:

```
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*5}{*3} 
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*5}{*3}
```

Without the titlesec package I tried to use the commands given in the KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 


\usepackage[headsepline=0.4pt]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles


\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.5\baselineskip]{section}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Test}
Text beginns here....
\end{document}
```

Comment: it does work, but such spaces are normally removed at page breaks. Add a second section to see this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, but what do you mean by "it does work". What do I have to put after "beforeskip=xxx\baselineskip". It does not change the spacing before the section. I am talking about the distance between the header and the actual section title. It was so easy with the titlesec package but its not possible to use it anymore.

Comment: @MJK Add an example where `titlesec` does what you want using standard class `article`. But I think, you have to use a report or a book class and chapters to get the desired result. Then you have to switch to `scrreprt` and `\chapter`.

Comment: @esdd  I used the titlesec package in the past for this type of command but I am not going to use it anymore because of incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec.

Comment: I know that `titlesec` and KOMA-Script are incompatible. But you can show what you did in the past with `titlesec` using the standard class `article`.

Comment: @esdd I added the commands, which I used in the past for the titlesec package to my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[headsepline=0.4pt]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearpairofpagestyles

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=5\baselineskip,% enlarged for demonstration
  afterskip=0.5\baselineskip]{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\newpage
\section{Test}
Text beginns here.
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Note that the `beforeskip` is removed if the section title is at top of the page.

So maybe you want to use `scrreprt` and `\chapter` to get the desired result:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[headsepline=0.4pt,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearpairofpagestyles

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=5\baselineskip,% enlarged for demonstration
  afterskip=0.5\baselineskip]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\newpage
\chapter{Test}
Text beginns here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. "Note that the beforeskip is removed if the section title is at top of the page". So changing the document class from scrartcl to scrreprt and using \chapter is the only workaround?